# Saving file with date and user django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am making an **UPLOAD page** and i want a **model** that will hold a link to the file uploaded, the date and the user.
I'm really new to django and i'm confused about the r*elation between the forms and the models and how to pass data.*

I want to make a **1 field form**, which will be the FileField and catch request.user and time on the go, then save them in database 
This is my code so far:

**forms.py**

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    docfile=forms.FileField(label="Select a file")
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def upload(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        form=UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            #this is what i used to save the only the file
            #now i want to have file,user and upload date in db
            new_doc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            new_doc.save()

            print(request.user)
            **???**-what do i insert here to pass user and time
            to the model and save it **???**


            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('after_upload'))

    else:


        form=UploadForm()

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Document(models.Model):


    upload_user=**???**
    upload_time=**???**

    docfile=models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do something like this,

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Document(models.Model):
    upload_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='documents')
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    docfile  =models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m')
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('docfile',)
```

**views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
    doc = form.save(commit=False)
    doc.upload_user = request.user
    doc.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('after_upload'))
```